# How can I get my build folders in the next stage in Jenkins

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I am trying to deploy a react app to my vagrant machine running in my Mac using Jenkins pipeline.

After I successfully build the app, the build folder is only resident in the build stage. This build folder is not seen in the next stage. When ever I try to list the content of the build folder in the next stage after building I get this error;

```
ls: cannot access './build': No such file or directory
```

I have already archived the folder but I keep getting the same error.

This is my pipeline;

```
@Library('shared-library') _
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages{
        stage("Test"){
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:lts-alpine'
                    args '-u root:root'
                }
            }
            steps{
                sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                sh './app/scripts/test.sh'
            }
        }
        stage("Build"){
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:lts-alpine'
                    args '-u root:root'
                }
            }
            steps{
                dir('./app'){
                    sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                    sh "npm install"
                    sh "./scripts/deliver-for-development.sh"
                
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: "build/**", fingerprint: true
                }
                
            }
        }

        stage("Deliver for Development"){
            agent any
            when {
                branch "development"
            }
            steps{
                sh 'ls ./build'
            }
        }
   }
}
```

This is the content of ./scripts/deliver-for-development.sh script in the pipeline.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
npm run build
set +x
```

Please how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stash to copy files from one stage to another,
[stashing Jenkins files to other stages](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)

Should look similar to this,

```js
@Library('shared-library') _
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages{
        stage("Test"){
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:lts-alpine'
                    args '-u root:root'
                }
            }
            steps{
                sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                sh './app/scripts/test.sh'
            }
        }
        stage("Build"){
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:lts-alpine'
                    args '-u root:root'
                }
            }
            steps{
                dir('./app'){
                    sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                    sh "npm install"
                    sh "./scripts/deliver-for-development.sh"
                    stash includes: 'build/**', name: 'buildfiles'
                }    
            }
        }

        stage("Deliver for Development"){
            agent any
            when {
                branch "development"
            }
            steps{
                unstash 'buildfiles'
                sh 'ls ./build'
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the build stage, its building inside the docker and in the immediate next stage, the agent is lost and jenkins might be looking at different location than the previous stage docker.
If do ls immediately after this step,
sh "./scripts/deliver-for-development.sh"
you can see the contents.
You can either copy the build folder during the build step to some location in the controller and deploy it.